# How to get the value from dropdown in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am using dropdown in ASP.net to display image along with value

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddBanner" runat="server" CssClass="ddBanner"  >
</asp:DropDownList>
```

I used the following link to modify to my needs, i got it working. 
http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/12/jquery-bind-images-to-dropdownlist-in.html

I need to get the dropdown value, which i am finding hard in my case. 
when i use ddBanner.SelectedValue or ddBanner.selectedItem or ddBanner.text it gets me "1.png" while i want the "1" to store in the database, below is the value after i run the webpage

```
<select id="MainContent_ddBanner" class="ddBanner" name="ctl00$MainContent$ddBanner">
<option title="../ImagesBanners/1.png" value="1.png">1</option>
<option title="../ImagesBanners/2.png" value="2.png">3</option>
<option title="../ImagesBanners/3.png" value="3.png">6</option>
</select>
```

What should i do to get the  "1" or "2" from the drop down. i also need to pre select the value store in data base when i am update the same data .

data Example:
**PageTable**
PageName, PageTitle, PageBannerID
Home ,    Welcome to our site, 1

Banner table

BannerID, BannerImage

1, 1.png
2, b.png
3, 3.png

Comment: Please show us the code you use to populate the DropDownList.

Comment: @StudentDubai Pardon me for my curiosity, but do you live in Dubai?

Comment: Are you wanting to get the value using jquery? Your question doesnt mention that at all, but it is in the tags for the question.

Comment: If you want to store "1" instead of "1.png", why not make "1" the value instead of 1.png?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
ddBanner.selectedItem.Text
```

Comment: I marked you answer as it is the exact match and worked, Some of the other user had also mentioned logically you where the first so marked your answer. Thanks to you and other guys also..

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for

**ASP.NET**

```
ddBanner.SelectedItem.Text
```

**jQuery**

**Edit:**

If you are not using a MasterPage:

```
$("#ddBanner option:selected").text();
```

Since you are using a MasterPage:

```
$('[id$=ddBanner] option:selected').text();
```

Comment: That's correct, but I think it's still a wrong approach - the OP stores data he doesn't really need. if he`s looking for "1" rather than "1.png" then "1.png" is obviously redundant

Comment: @Shai I agree; it does seem weird. If anything the 1.png should be in the text and the value should be 1. There should be no need for 1.png to be in the value field unless it is what you are wanting to put in the db.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".ddBanner option:selected").val().replace(".png","");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".ddBanner option:selected").text();
```